# Why are my images and css not showing up on my website?

Tags: wordpress, media-library, wordpress-media

I have a  problem with my website which is built in WordPress. My uploaded images don't list in the Media Library and CSS does not show on the website.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. Please make it clear to understand, What I understand is maybe your images are not uploaded properly, try to upload them properly. If you are using a cache plugin then deactivate it, Clear cookies. Also, you can use a different browser or incognito window. Use Ctrl + F5 to refresh your site.